# Require the customer to authenticate before placing an order

Tags: magento2, checkout, login, register

Is there any functionality in magento 2 that will force the user to register when passing the checkout. If the user does not have an account, do not allow him to buy

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable guest checkout, customers must then create an account to place an order.

> To disable guest checkout: In the Sales section in the left panel,
>   choose Checkout. Expand the Checkout Options section. If necessary,
>   clear the Use system value checkbox. If the setting is for a specific
>   store view, choose the store view where the configuration applies.

From https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/checkout-guest.html